# ECMAScript-6 import a nested function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi I switched over to ECMAScript-6 javascript syntax a little while ago and am loving it! One thing I noticed and couldn't find a definitive answer on is using nested destructing syntax on an import. What I mean is something like this..

Lets say I have a file that looks like this.

```
export const SomeUtils = _.bindAll({ //lodash _
    someFunc1(params){
        // .... stuff here
    },
    someFunc2(params){
        // .... stuff here
    },
    someFunc3(params){
        // .... stuff here
    }
});
// ... many more of these
```

I have been doing something like this to get a specific function

```
import {Utils} from '../some/path/to/utils';
var {someFunc2} = Utils;
```

To get to the point.. Is there a way to do a single line import for `someFunc2`? like how you can do the nested object destruction assignment with brackets? (Aka: `{Utils: [{someFunc2}]}`) ?

I used to do `var someFunc2 = require('../some/path/to/utils').someFunc2;` but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with an import statement

Comment: Do you mean `export class Utils`?

Comment: @saadq no, its just an object with utility functions in it

Comment: Your syntax seems off in that case. Did you mean [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d6225f6fa51c363537e)? You should have the `=` before the `{` and you need to add commas between methods.

Comment: @saadq yea sure, its just a simple example I wrote on the fly. but yea. I'll update it with some more details to make it syntactically correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, ES6 module imports do not provide a destructuring option. The only feature they have are named exports (but without nesting). They are meant to exactly replace your `require(…).someFunc2` pattern.

---

In your specific case, I don't see any reason why you would be exporting a single object as a named export. Just use

```
export function someFunc1(params){
    // .... stuff here
}
export function someFunc2(params){
    // .... stuff here
}
export function someFunc3(params){
    // .... stuff here
}
```

so that you then can do

```
import {someFunc2} from '../some/path/to/utils';
```

Comment: the problem is this utility file has grouped utilities.. so some are for url's some are for media.. etc (about 100 utility functions). and its a work file I didn't make (it was there when I started working here). but thanks for the answer. I'll just keep doing what I have been doing!

Comment: You might want to split that into multiple modules then. Otherwise, just use two lines for destructuring

Comment: @JohnRuddell: My answer was assuming that your complete utils file looked like what you posted, just ignore the second part if that's not the case

Comment: Yea I may make a task to do that in the near future and update all the files to do that. And I know its hard to post everything thats relevant without posting too much code lol. No worries. I'll mess around with it some more and see what the best avenue is :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Just using `… // lots of these` is fine in questions :-)

Comment: true.. shoulda thought of that. Thanks again for the answer though. I wonder if that would be a feature at some point in time. might be cool :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: I'm pretty sure there's an ES7 proposal for it somewhere… Would be quite useful and trivial to extend in the spec; albeit a bit confusing to mix the two given that you need to use `as` for named exports and `:` for object properties.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve what you are looking for you need to export as default:

```
const Utils = _.bindAll({ //lodash _
    someFunc1(params){
        // .... stuff here
    },
    someFunc2(params){
        // .... stuff here
    },
    someFunc3(params){
        // .... stuff here
    }
});

export default Utils;
```

You can then either import the whole thing of just what you need...

```
import Utils, { someFunc2 } from '../some/path/to/utils';
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. There's no export with the name `someFunc2` in here.

Comment: @Maroshii i didn't downvote, but I can tell you that wont work because to import something from a file (the way you are proposing) has to be exported. the default is an object whose child is the someFunc2.. which wont work. That import is saying import the sibling of Utils called someFunc2 not the child of Utils

Comment: @Bergi. Updated the answer. It does work. it's just that `default const` can't be declared inline .

Comment: Please remove the downvote, this works and it's a perfectly valid solution. It even allows for importing the entire object which the accepted answer doesn't as it exports individual functions

Comment: I just tried it. still doesnt work. and it doesn't answer my question because even if it did work it would only be for the default and not any additional functions

Comment: I don't know how you are importing it BUT THIS WORKS and it's a pattern seen very often: `import React, {Component} from 'react'`.

Comment: @Maroshii: Yes, but react does use a named export for `Component`, not a property of the default-exported `React` object.

Comment: @Bergi no it doesn't. It exports a single `React` object as default so `React.Component` and `Component` is the same object.

Comment: @Maroshii: Yes, it might refer to the same object, but the property and the export are two different things. Or if they aren't, that's just how the non-standard transpilation works for you.